# Safari + Voiceover issue when reading input field

Tags: html, safari, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have set `aria-describedby` to an input field, but whenever the user starts typing, only in Safari, voiceover interrupts reading the description and reads the value again.

I actually checked it is a Safari specific behavior and it reads first the last digit and after you stop typing it reads the entire value, like "one-two" - small pause- "twelve" ;

The HTML is pretty straight-forward:

`<input type="text" aria-labelledby="sample-label" aria-describedby="disclaimer"/><div class="offset" id="disclaimer">Some description here</div><div id="sample-label">Some label here</div>`

I checked and it works properly for Chrome;

Does anyone know if there's something I can do about it?

Comment: Is that the complete input with no associated `<label>`? The behaviour you describe is expected (and therefore you do not need to do anything about it), but having a properly associated label is essential as screen reader support is 100% for a label on an input and about 80% for `aria-describedby`. With a label there are also shortcuts to re announce the current input name so typing and interrupting is not an issue.

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie, I really appreciate your comment. My real-world scenario has the ```aria-labelledby``` attribute set, but not a ```label``` tag explicitly. Do you believe this could have any impact?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we are still not in a position where `aria` has enough support to rely on it solely. It should be used to add additional semantic information but not to replace things that are built into HTML. Quick question, is the idea to have a label and then associate some additional information with the input? If so I can put a quick answer together for you.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. Thanks